# hbase completebulkload long running

Tags: hadoop, hbase, bulk-load

A hadoop cluster was upgraded from CDH 4.4 to CDH 5.7.6, HBASE: 0.94 -> 1.2.0
After that time of hbase completebulkload process has increased from 2 hours to 3-4 for small tables and 10+ hours for big tables. Why it happens? What should I check for?

Comment: check the parameters of old and new installation some of them might have corrupted

Comment: I suppose it's due a lot of compactions. I found the following parameter: hbase.regionserver.thread.compaction.small. is it good idea to increase it?

Comment: first thing is you need to make sure that you have data evenly/uniformly distribute across region servers(neat rowkey design with salting) to avoid hot spots in to one region. based on that you can take decision on compactions which is relavent...

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in disabled blockcache. If you load hfiles through the code using LoadIncrementalHFiles it works properly.
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HBASE-10500